# JavaScript: functional reducer without if checks?

Tags: javascript

I have a reducer function that runs multiple times and 'reflects' the input object, mapping params to different `key: value` pairs

```
function tallyReducer (updates) {
    let result = {};

    if (updates.parentX || updates.parentY) {
        result.top = updates.parentY;
        result.left = updates.parentX;

    } else if (updates.baseX || updates.baseY) {
        result.left = updates.baseX + 20;
        result.top = updates.baseY + 20;

    } else if (updates.offsetX || updates.offsetY) {
        result.left = updates.offsetX + 20;
        result.top = updates.offsetY + 20;
    }

    if (updates.opacity) result.opacity = updates.opacity;

    return result;
}
```

Is there a way that I can avoid the `if` checks, without ever returning

`{ top: undefined, opacity: 1 }` or `{ top: 20, opacity: undefined }` ?

Because this is running 60 times per second, I want to directly map the properties, rather than running by all of the if statements.

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot avoid the conditionals, unless you know beforehand how `updates` will look like. Do you? Then you could use different reducers and choose one dynamically.

Comment: This code running at 60Hz is *absolutely nothing to worry about*. Avoid [premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation).

Comment: @Bergi the intern's project broke chrome with Aw Snap, but not canary, which may be due to es6 / es7, but she's just mapping a mouse event through a series of reducers. the heap is building and garbage collecting repeatedly, which is probably normal. overall calculations happen in less than 1ms, but still, we have many, many, many reducers. thank you for the moral support though

Comment: and i only know that the updates sometimes have values, and sometimes they don't, but i don't want to pass off undefined values if the input object didn't have them